# saving array values in each new row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have tried for sometime and i think i got it wrong.

The form that i use is a nested form with fields_for and all i wanted is to save each of the array values in the rails select function into new rows in the db.

I have serialized :newpages in my blackwhite.rb model.

```
     <% forms_for @prints do |f| %>
      ...
      ...

        <%= f.fields_for :blackwhites_attributes do |blackwhite| %>
        <%= blackwhite.select :newpages , options_for_select((1..(@print.number_of_images_entry.to_i)).to_a), :multiple => true, :size => @print.number_of_images_entry.to_i %>
        <% end %>

     <% end %>
```

Edit 1:

It has "multiple" as i wanted to have multiple selections for the pages.

blackwhite.rb model:

```
class Blackwhite < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessible :print_id

      serialize :newpages
      belongs_to :print

    end
```

print.rb model:

```
class Print < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blackwhites
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blackwhites, :allow_destroy => true

 ...
 ...
end
```

Update 2:

I have watched railscasts and had modified my nested forms as below:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :blackwhites do |blackwhite| %>
       <% render 'blackwhites', f: blackwhite %>
    <% end %>
```

in partial _blackwhites.html.erb:

```
   <%= f.select :newpages , (1..(@print.number_of_images_entry)), { :prompt => "0" }, :multiple => true, :size => @print.number_of_images_entry ) %>
```

and my select fields is no longer appearing.

Comment: How does you model look like? Does it have a `has_many` relation between prints and blackwhites? And then i don't understand why you use the multiple => true option here, if you want to store them in multiple rows... Please check out as well rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised there you get a really good introduction to nested forms.

Comment: Yes, print has_many blackwhites. i'm just confused on putting the data into every rows.

the multiple option is for selecting multiple pages at a time, but i could be wrong at how it's thought of. - saving these inputs into rows of a new table (blackwhite).

for nested forms it is straightforward with @print.blackwhites.build for the has_many relation, into the controller. (i would be using edit) - and i don't have a railscasts pro account. :(

Comment: Have you watched the railscast episode? I think there is everything explained very well.

Comment: yes and i have modified it accordingly. the select field no longer works.

Comment: yes. it worked. together with the solution by basgys and adding @print.blackwhites.build in edit action of print controller. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render is not printed because you forgot the equal sign.

```
<%= render 'blackwhites', f: blackwhite %>
```